# How to delete from Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQsQ2injLo

This explains how to save and retrieve from the database, but not how to delete. I am wondering how to delete the database node that belongs to the cell that is being deleted. Thanks

Comment: use remove function to delete

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit. Code updated for **Swift 3** and **Swift 4**.

I'm always using the remove with completion handler:

```
static let ref = Database.database().reference()

static func remove(child: String) {

    let ref = self.ref.child(child)

    ref.removeValue { error, _ in

        print(error)
    }
}
```

So for example if I want to delete the following value:

[image]

I call my function: `remove(child: "mixcloudLinks")`

If I want to go deeper and delete for example "added":

[image]

I need to change the function a little bit.

```
static func remove(parentA: String, parentB: String, child: String) {

    self.ref.child("mixcloudLinks").child(parentA).child(parentB).child(child)

    ref.removeValue { error, _ in

        print(error)   
    }
}
```

Called like:

```
let parentA = "DDD30E1E-8478-AA4E-FF79-1A2371B70700"
let parentB = "-KSCRJGNPZrTYpjpZIRC"
let child = "added"
remove(parentA: parentA, parentB: parentB, child: child)
```

This would delete just the key/value "added"

**EDIT**

In case of autoID, you need to save the autoID into your Dictionary to be able to use it later.

This is for example one of my functions:

```
func store(item: MyClassObject) {

    var item = item.toJson()

    let ref = self.ref.child("MyParentFolder").childByAutoId()
    item["uuid"] = ref.key // here I'm saving the autoID key into the dictionary to be able to delete this item later
    ref.setValue(item) { error, _ in

        if let error = error {

           print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Because then I'm having the autoID as part of my dictionary and am able to delete it later:

[image]

Then I can use it like `.child(MyClassObject.uuid).remove...` which is then the automatic generated id.

Comment: Thank you for the reply David. The problem is that i am saving the values with autoId, so then I don´t know the key.

Comment: you need to save the autoID into your item.

Comment: done. i think this should give you the idea of how to delete it

Comment: Thank you David, i have not tested this yet, but i think this might be the solution!

Comment: i'm sure it is... glad to help you. if you need further assistance, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Thank you David, you are a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 0):

we can store the randomly generated id as the user id in the database and retrieve that to delete

for e.g. :

```
let key = ref?.childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": key,
                "name": myName,
                "task": myTask]

    ref?.child(key!).setValue(post)
```

in order to delete 
setvalue of the id as nil
for e.g. :

```
 var key = [string]()
ref?.child(key[indexPath.row]).setValue(nil)
    key.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    myTable.reloadData()
```