# Remove the clicked item in swift and firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small application which shows a list of all items from a Firebase Database. I have added a delete button to my custom cell and I want to delete that field from firebase when I click it. Here is how my items and the delete button looks like [image]

And this is my database [image]

Comment: take a look here, already answered: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632775/8236481)

Comment: Where is your current code? What is below the autoids? How do the values in your data source related to the material displayed in your tableView?