# When allowing a user to delete their account it only deletes their account authentication and that is not enough

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Allowing a user to delete their account is no issue for deleting their account authentication with the following code.

```
func deleteUser()
{
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    user?.delete
        {
            error in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("ERROR DELETING ACCOUNT")
            }
            else
            {
                print("ACCOUNT DELETED")
            }
    }
}
```

This works ok but does nothing to the user ID and all the attached children in the Realtime Database.

How do I simultaneously allow the removal of the user ID and connected children from the Realtime Database?

Comment: Within the block that prints `ACCOUNT DELETED`, you need to take the uid and delete the user node from real time database. An answer for deleting from realtime database can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631998/how-to-delete-from-firebase-database

Comment: Thanks for the direction, that ACCOUNT DELETED block would be too late to do anything as the answer from Doug Stevenson made me aware of but you helped me search for a suitable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this truly simultaneously.  You'll want to delete the database items first, while the signed in user still has a valid ID token to use that identifies the user to Realtime Database.  This could be important for evaluating security rules.  Only after all the database work is done, should the account be deleted.

If you want to do this with a backend instead, you could use Cloud Functions to write a [Firebase Auth onDelete trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) that deletes everything for the user *after* the delete happens on the client. This is OK because you will also use the Firebase Admin SDK to delete all the data, and it bypasses all security rules.

Comment: You helped me as an amateur think about this more logically so I could do it in one function

Answer (score 1):

To data in the database that is associated with the user is a quite common request. In fact, it's so common that there's a dedicated Github repo: [User Data Protection](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/user-data-protection). The code in this repo essentially does what Doug describes:

> ... a Cloud Function triggered by account deletion (an Auth.delete event) that wipes out all the data in the Firebase Realtime Database that belonged to the deleted user.

You can configure precisely what data belong to the user, with a JSON specification (called wipeout rules). You can either write your own wipeout rules, or [auto-extract](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/user-data-protection/blob/master/doc/auto_rules_extraction.md) (an initial version of) them from your security rules.

The same functionality is also available in a Firebase Extension called [Delete User Data](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/delete-user-data/). You can install this in the Firebase console of your project, and can then configure what data gets deleted from Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and/or Cloud Storage.

Comment: Upvoted this because the options make sense for a more sophisticated data deletion. I’m keeping it as simplistic as I can without the use of more modules, API’s etc

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the contributors trying to help with this question.

I've at least got everything happening as I want, without having to add things I didn't want.

Inside the deleteUser function I placed a deleteUserData function

```
func deleteUser()
{

//  Placed right here ↓↓↓   
         deleteUserData()

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

user?.delete
    {
        error in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("ERROR DELETING ACCOUNT")
        }
        else
        {
            print("ACCOUNT DELETED")
        }
    }
}
```

The function firstly gets rid of the secondary children followed by the user ID with all account children attached at the same time as deleting the account.

```
func deleteUserData()
{
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        else
    {
        return
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(user).child("scores").removeValue(
        completionBlock:
        {
            (error, refer) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print(error as Any)
            }
            else
            {
                print(refer)
                print("REMOVED CHILDREN FIRST FROM USER")

                ref.child("users").child(user).removeValue(
                    completionBlock:
                    {
                        (error, refer) in
                        if error != nil
                        {
                            print(error as Any)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print(refer)
                            print("COMPLETELY REMOVED ALL USER DATA")
                        }
                })
            }
    })
}
```

(Hopefully there's nothing wrong with doing it all this way but considering it works perfectly, I'm happy. Also happy to be told why it shouldn't be done this way)✌